# Tinymce - validate cell width in cell properties or is it possible to set min width for any column?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

We need to validate the cell width less than 10px need to show error message.
Is there any option please let us know.

Also, is it possible to set min width for column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

About this: "Also, is it possible to set min width for column."
It`s possible that you set a minimum width in css styles.

You can set default styles in content_style property

example:

```
init {
  ...,
  content_style: 'th,tr { min-width: 10px; }'
}
```

URL documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style